# Disable a button when max is reached using keyboard arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to disable a button when a maximum is reached in a number `input`.

I can get this working with *clicking* the button, but not when using the keyboard's **up/down arrow keys** (or the input's implicit arrows).

I think there is something fundamental that not I'm quite understanding...

```js
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const max = 5;

  function handleClick() {
    setValue((v) => +v + 1);
  }

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setValue(() => value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="number" value={value} onChange={handleChange} max={max} />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick} disabled={value === max}>
        increase
      </button>
      <p>Button will disable at 5 when clicking `increase` button,<br /> but not when using keyboard arrow keys (inside input)</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add KeyDown eventhandler. I didnt add keycode check for ArrowDown and ArrowUp

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const max = 5;

  function handleClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if(value === max){
      return;
    }
    setValue(v => +v + 1);
  }

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setValue(() => value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="number"
        onKeyDown={e => handleClick(e)}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        max={max}
      />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick} disabled={value === max}>
        increase
      </button>
      <p>
        Button will disable at 5 when clicking `increase` button,
        <br /> but not when using keyboard arrow keys (inside input)
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it increases the value by two when using keyboard but more importantly, it will lag by one when disabling the button. Also, using the implicit arrow controls won't disable the button.